# Laravel DELETE request outside of form - Getting the data

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm using this script to send a `DELETE` request using a button outside of a form. https://gist.github.com/nickdavies791/f547b64e2ad432c9d43ba93758ed168b

The form submits perfectly fine and adds the `@csrf` tag and the delete method to the form but no data is sent.

What I can't understand is how to append the data that I want to send to that form, because the form is appended to the `<body>` tag.

So basically what I have is this:

```
<!-- Submit button -->
<a href="{{ secure_url('assets/delete') }}" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="DELETE">Dispose</a>

@foreach($assets as $asset)
    <table>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{ $asset->id }}"></td>
        <td>{{ $asset->name }}</td>
    </table>
@endforeach

<!-- Form that gets appended by script -->
<form method="POST" action="https://asset-manager.test/assets/delete">
  <input name="_token" value="HIV3JlPpUftvgrtcL9Irr3kIxMSFff6utpdeMSba" type="hidden">
  <input name="_method" value="DELETE" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: you want to delete multiple data at same time or single data

Comment: It's multiple data. I have it all set up and it works if I add the form manually wrapped around the table and button, any checked data gets deleted from the array. However, using this script, no data is sent through the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an id to your form and then add `<input form="form_id">` then use it anywhere you want.
Even outside of form.

```
<form method="POST" id="my_app_form" action="https://asset-manager.test/assets/delete">
<!-- Hidden form fields -->
</form>

<!-- Any other markup here -->

<input form="my_app_form" type="text" name="my_data" value="{{ $your->data }}"/>

<!-- Any other markup here -->
```